# missing param for named route "x"

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-test-utils

I am trying to test this code:

```
template(#item.id='props')
        router-link(:to='{ name:"ticketDetail", params: { ticketId: props.item.shortId }}')
          | {{ props.item.shortId }}
```

The test:

```
  it('should pass in the correct props to router-link', () => {
    const routerLinkStub = resultsTable.findAll('router-link');
    expect(wrapper.find('router-link').exists()).toBeTruthy();
    
  });
```

I am getting this warning though:

```
[vue-router] missing param for named route "ticketDetail": Expected "ticketId" to match "[^\/]+?", but received ""
```

Any idea what may be going wrong? Any help is appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide your router config for this route